# Can't push Docker image to Amazon ECR - fails with "no basic auth credentials"

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecr

My linux terminal was giving me this error **"no basic auth credentials"**  while tryin to push the docker image to ecr, but after earching a lot and trying out everything it did't resolve.

Answer (score 1):

But now, **I got the solution** and it is whenever **you configure aws credetials with aws configure command do it with sudo user** bcz when when push something it needs a sudo permission and searched the set credentails in sudo environment but actaully we configured the credentials in normal user. it is just a small mistake but ignire it always. thank me if it works.

****sudo su**
**aws configure**
**then try pushing****